# Rspec - obvious test is failing, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a very simple app I'm trying to test with rspec.  I'm having a hard time figuring out if my configuration is the problem, or if it's the code.  The first line of /people/index.html.erb is `<h1>Totally Awesome Page</h1>`.

The error:

```
expected to find text "Totally Awesome Page" in "Index"
./spec/features/people_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <class:PeopleSpec>'
```

test gems:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

spec/features/people_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

class PeopleSpec < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  describe "People" do

    describe "Index" do

     before { visit '/people'}

      it { should have_content('Totally Awesome Page')}

    end
  end
end
```

spec/spec_helper:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.order = "random"
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

routes:

```
people_path     GET     /people(.:format)   people#index
              POST  /people(.:format)   people#create
new_person_path     GET     /people/new(.:format)   people#new
edit_person_pathGET     /people/:id/edit(.:format)  people#edit
person_path     GET     /people/:id(.:format)   people#show
              PATCH     /people/:id(.:format)   people#update
              PUT   /people/:id(.:format)   people#update
              DELETE    /people/:id(.:format)   people#destroy
```

Comment: check the `launchy` gem. It's awesome in that kind of specs.

Comment: Show `rake routes` for that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `gem 'launchy'` and then you can use `save_and_open_page` after `visit` to see how rendered page looks like.

Add `subject { page }` to the spec to fix it.

If you say `it` than it have to point to something. In your test it doesn't.
You can use `should` on `page` to do that (`page` is not the only one you can test. There are more, like `response` or even lambdas) that way:

```
it "some description" do
  page.should have_content('foo')
end
```

or if you have many tests for `page` than you can write them in a short way:

```
it { should have_content('foo') }
```

but you need to specify subject for `it` first:

```
subject { page }
```

Comment: I can launch the page with this command.  The correct page is shown with 'Totally Awesome Page' as the title.

Comment: add `subject { page }`